# ggplot dot covering error bar

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a huge file and I don't really know what small test dataset I can give here to produce the same problem in the plot, so I will not give any test dataset, I will only attach the plot image here to show the problem.

[image]

My code:

```
ggplot(tgc, aes(x=Week, y=MuFreq)) + 
theme_gray(base_size=18) + 
theme(plot.title=element_text(hjust=.5), 
      axis.title.x = element_text(face="bold"),
      axis.title.y = element_text(face="bold")) + 
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=MuFreq-(1.96*se), ymax=MuFreq+(1.96*se)), width=3) +
geom_line() +
geom_point(aes(size= N), color="blue")+
scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(68,98,188), labels=c("Wk68", "Wk98", "Wk188")) +
scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,0.15)) +
scale_size( breaks = unique(tgc$N))
```

So the problem is that I'm sizing the dots based on the sample size for each week, the middle dot actually has error bars associated with it but it's covering the error bar. I tried to use horizontal error bar but it didn't work because my x-axis is customized to be non-numerical.

**What can I do to show the error bar that's being covered?**

Also is there any way to make the background vertical grid lines spaced evenly?

Comment: What if you put your `geom_points` call before the `geom_errorbar`? `ggplot` will plot the points and then the error bars on top of them if you do it that way. You could also try passing `alpha = 0.5` inside your `geom_points` call to make the points more transparent.

Comment: good idea and it shows but blue is too dark so i changed it to white, but it's too light, what's a good color to use?

Comment: If your error bars are black, you can probably use the `geom_points(alpha = 0.5)` idea or try a lighter blue. Maybe `dogerblue1`? A full list of `R` colors can be found [here](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~tzheng/files/Rcolor.pdf). You could also try `theme_bw()` call to make all your colors stand out more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Q asks to improve two things in the `ggplot2` chart:

1. Show error bars that are being covered
2. Make the background vertical grid lines spaced evenly

### Data

As the OP didn't supply any data, we need a dummy data set. This is easily done by reading values from the plot:

```
tgc <- data.frame(Week = c(68, 98, 188),
                  MuFreq = c(0.08, 0.09, 0.091),
                  se = c(0.003, 0.001, 0.019)/1.96,
                  N = c(91, 835, 7))
```

This reproduces the original plot quite nicely:

[image]

### Variant 1

This one is picking up Nick Criswell's comments:

- Change order in which layers are plotted, so that error bars are plotted on top
- Change colour and alpha

plus

- Remove all vertical grid lines except those which are explicetly specified as breaks. The distances of major grid lines are still uneven but reflect the difference in time

With this code

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(tgc, aes(x = Week, y = MuFreq)) +
  theme_gray(base_size = 18) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = .5),
        axis.title = element_text(face = "bold")) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(aes(size = N), color = "dodgerblue1", alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = MuFreq - (1.96 * se), 
                    ymax = MuFreq + (1.96 * se)), width = 3) +
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = c(68, 98, 188),
    labels = c("Wk68", "Wk98", "Wk188"),
    minor_breaks = NULL
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 0.15)) +
  scale_size(breaks = unique(tgc$N))
```

we do get:

[image]

### Variant 2

To get evenly spaced data points on the x-axis we can turn weeks into factor. This requires to tell `ggplot2` that the data belong to one group in order to have lines plotted and to add a custom x-axis label.

In addition, `theme_bw` is used instead of `theme_gray`:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(tgc, aes(x = factor(Week, labels = c("Wk68", "Wk98", "Wk188")), 
                y = MuFreq, group = 1)) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 18) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = .5),
        axis.title = element_text(face = "bold")) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(aes(size = N), color = "dodgerblue1", alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = MuFreq - (1.96 * se),
                    ymax = MuFreq + (1.96 * se)), width = 0.05 ) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 0.15)) +
  scale_size(breaks = unique(tgc$N)) + 
  xlab("Week")
```

[image]